# How to use javascript to get an ASP.NET's Textbox Control's Value

Tags: asp.net, javascript

Suppose I have an ASP.NET Text Box as Below :

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity" runat="server" Text="0"></asp:TextBox>
```

I want to get this box's current value in javascript. How can I access this element?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

use the clientID property

```
document.getElementByID('<%=txtQuantity.ClientID %>')
```

More information [here](http://blogs.telerik.com/atanaskorchev/posts/08-06-06/the_difference_between_id_clientid_and_uniqueid.aspx)

you can also use `find`

Quoted from the above link:

> Additionaly the ClientID is used in
>   ASP.NET Ajax as the unique identifier
>   of client-side controls. Thus the
>   following JavaScript statement is
>   commonly used:
>
> var control = $find("<%=
>   MyControl1.ClientID %>");

Answer (score 2):

You can get the client side ID using `txtQuantity.ClientID`.